# How to check if Hashtable contains specific key?

Tags: java, hashtable

I have a `ArrayList<String>` and a `Hashtable<String, Double>`. So when I compare the arraylist with hash table, if the key(string) is found I want to get the value(double) and find the total value at the end when all the arraylist is compared.  But it's giving score 0 always.

There is the code

```
ArrayList<String> Trigram = Trigrams.GenerateTrigrams(extra, 3);

// System.out.print(Trigram);
Hashtable<String, Double> map = readModleFile("Models//EnglishModel.txt");

double score = 0;

for (String temKey : Trigram) {
  if (map.contains(temKey)) {
    Double value = map.get(temKey);
    score = score + value;
  } else {
    score = 0;

  }

}
System.out.print(score);
```

Comment: Remove the `else`.

Comment: Just a suggestion - I think your loop can be reduced to `for (String temKey : trigram) if (map.contains(temKey)) score += map.get(temKey);`

Comment: It still prints out 0.0 only

Comment: `double score = Trigram.stream().filter(map::contains).mapToDouble(map::get).reduce(Double::sum).orElse(0);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems in your code:

1. Using `contains` instead of `containsKey`.
2. The `else` block is resetting `score` to `0` whenever the specified key is not found. Remove the `else` block.

You can also simplify your code as follows:

The following 4 lines

```
if (map.containsKey(temKey)) {
    Double value = map.get(temKey);
    score = score + value;
}
```

can be replaced with just one line

```
score += map.getOrDefault(temKey, 0);
```

Comment: My score gets printed as 0 again.

Comment: if (map.contains(temKey)) {
       system.out.print(temKey)
      } 

     this even doesn't prints the temKey

Comment: That's what I am also guessing i.e. `map` does not have any of the keys in `Trigram`. If you know how to use the debugger in your IDE, it will be easier for you to find the problem. If you do not know how to use it, I highly recommend you learn it as soon as possible. For now, just print the `List` and the `Map` i.e. `System.out.println(Trigram);` and `System.out.println(map);` to find the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Your `else` branch is always resetting the score to 0; the score will always be reset at least once unless the map contains all of the elements of the list. Simply remove the branch.

The second problem is that you are using [`contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#contains-java.lang.Object-), which checks for a value being present, instead of [`containsKey`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#containsKey-java.lang.Object-), which checks for the presence of a key.

```
for (String temKey : Trigram) {
  if (map.containsKey(temKey)) {
    Double value = map.get(temKey);
    score = score + value;
  }
}
```

The code can also be shortened and made more concise using [`getOrDefault`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-), which will either return the mapping associated with the key or the second argument (default value) if there is no mapping associated with the key.

```
for (String temKey : Trigram) {
  score += map.getOrDefault(temKey, 0);
}
```

Comment: It still prints out 0.0 only

Comment: @cloud123 Could you please provide a reproducible example of the problem?

Comment: @cloud123 I have edited my answer. See if it works now.

Comment: I checked my hash map and arraylist is perfect, just  from the if statement,  program is not working,

Comment: if (map.contains(temKey)) { system.out.print(temKey) } this even doesn't prints the temKey

Comment: @cloud123 Please reread my revised answer. You should be using `map.containsKey` instead of `map.contains`.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `else` - it makes the score zero, every time the key is not present in the `map`.

Comment: It still prints out 0.0 only

Answer (score 0):

If the following does not work

```
System.out.println(map);     // debug statement
for (String temKey : Trigram) {
  System.out.println("temKey = " + "\"" + temKey + "\""); // debug statement
  if (map.containsKey(temKey)) {
    Double value = map.get(temKey);
    score = score + value;
  } 
}
```

Then check the `Trigram` list and the `HashTable` to ensure the case of the Strings are the same or that they even exist.  And make certain you are comparing "word" to "word" and don't have extraneous white space. So you may need to trim white space from the values.  And put in some debug statements like the above.